# Where exactly does the Carnaval de Barranquilla take place?

Tags: colombia, festivals, barranquilla

While it is said in National Geographic, the Rough Guide to Colombia and other publications that the Carnaval De Barranquilla is the second largest in the world, following the one in Brazil, I cannot find information on where it occurs in Barranquilla.

Do events follow a known route? Or occur in plazas or public squares? Is there a detailed schedule? Wikipedia says, Feb 6 - 9 for 2016, but that's not enough to be at the right place and time.

**Where does one need to go and at what time to have a reasonably good view of main events?**

Comment: Barranquilla is not that big. If you make sure you're there the right days, asking pretty much anyone will do the trick. If you don't speak Spanish, ask at the few big hotels. Or the Museum of the Caribbean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Barranquilla’s carnival 2016 program](http://colombiareports.com/booked-yet-barranquillas-carnival-announces-2016-program/), the festival takes place at many different locations around the city:

[image]

So you would have to go to different streets/stadiums depending on which day you'll be there.

There is also a detailed plan of the route which is incredibly useful since Via 40 is very long.

[image: Via 40 Parade Map]

Comment: Great find! Bonus for being a Google Calendar :)